# coding half a million circles in a pattern

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, geometry, drawing

I´ve been trying to make a desktop app (javascript, canvas) and draw 413.280 clickable circles in a certain pattern, but I can´t really figure out how to do it. I´m not convinced canvas is the best solution but I dont know how to solve this and get an app with a reasonable performance.

Here´s the layout I´m trying to get:
[circle layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp0UY.png)

I want 2 rows of circles within each line. the division in the middle is to be left empty.

Every left row has to be 588 circles.

Every right row has to be 560 circles

There are 180 lines on each side which means there's (588*2*180)= 211680 circles on the left side.

There's (560*2*180)=201600 circles on the right side.

can anyone point me in the right direction, maybe have a clue how I can solve this in the most efficient way possible? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: here's the JSFiddle I've got so far [jsfiddle.net/cmxLoqej/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/cmxLoqej/2/)

JavaScript

```
window.onload = draw;

function draw() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var ycoordinate = 20;

//draw the line 180 times
  for (var x = 1; x <= 180; x++) {

    // draw the left side
    for (var i = 1; i <= 1; i++){
        c.strokeStyle = 'black';
        c.moveTo(0,ycoordinate);
        c.lineTo(6468,ycoordinate);
        c.stroke();
        ycoordinate = ycoordinate + 40;
        }          
  }
 var ycoordinate = 20;

  //draw right side
    for (var x = 1; x <= 180; x++) {


        for (var j = 1; j <= 1; j++){
            c.strokeStyle = 'black';
            c.moveTo(6776,ycoordinate);
            c.lineTo(canvas.width,ycoordinate);
            c.stroke();
            ycoordinate = ycoordinate + 40;
        }
    }
}


var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var canvasPattern = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvasPattern.width=11;
  canvasPattern.height=20;
  var contextPattern = canvasPattern.getContext("2d");
  contextPattern.beginPath();

  contextPattern.arc(5, 10, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  contextPattern.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  contextPattern.stroke();
  var pattern = context.createPattern(canvasPattern,"repeat");
 context.fillStyle = pattern;
 context.fillRect(0, 20, 6468, 7160);
 context.fill();

 var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context2 = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var canvasPattern2 = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvasPattern2.width=11;
  canvasPattern2.height=20;
  var contextPattern2 = canvasPattern.getContext("2d");
  contextPattern2.beginPath();

  contextPattern2.arc(5, 10, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  contextPattern2.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  contextPattern2.stroke();
  var pattern2 = context2.createPattern(canvasPattern2,"repeat");
  context2.fillStyle = pattern;
  context2.fillRect(6776, 20, 6160, 7160);
  context2.fill();
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 
<canvas {
 id="canvas"; 
 width= "12936" ; 
 height ="7400";
 style= "border: 1px solid black;";
 padding: 0;
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
}>
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest, you do two steps (maybe three). 1. You draw the circles. (2. optional: You react on the mouse position while moving to draw a circle on top of an existing circle to give visual feedback) 3. You react on click and measure the mouse position to determine which circle was clicked

Comment: To make a circle or other shape respond to a click in canvas is quite expensive performance-wise. Please read the previous comment.  I would use SVG or maybe I would draw the circles as HTML elements.

Comment: @enxaneta what?!! To make a shape respond to a mouse event on a canvas is no more expansive than on svg elements, quite the contrary. Instead of having 413.280 EventTargets, each having their own pointer-events rules (stroke/fill/whatelse) you have only a single one. Canvas is far better suited for such a case. if we talk only about perfs.

Comment: It seems that you already have a solution. So what's your problem precisely ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I need to fill the rest of the 360 lines and make the circles clickable but I don't know how to. Sorry I'm not very experienced.

Comment: If you can create one clickable circle, you can create millions of them. It is just a matter of a few loops and coordinate computations, no ?

Comment: I'm sorry but i have no clue how to detect which circle is clicked and how to get these locations out of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use fill [patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasPattern) of circles to create rectangular canvas images of

- a single row of the left hand side
- a single row of the right hand side
- a combined row of each side
- a single canvas of 180 rows

Use temporary CANVAS objects along the way as necessary to use the [context2D.createPattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern) method. You should not need to add them to the DOM just to manipulate pixels.

Modify the algorithm if needed as you learn. Happy coding!

---

**Update** (edit)

Running the code added to the question shows all circles being evenly spaced horizontally ***and*** vertically.

A simpler way of drawing the canvas may be to fill two rectangles that exactly cover the left and right areas of the canvas with the circle pattern, and draw the grid lines on the canvas afterwards instead of before.

**Finding the circle clicked**

A click event listener on the canvas is passed a [mouse event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) object.

The classical way to determine which circle was clicked was to first perform arithmetic on the `screenX` and `screenY` event properties for screen position, `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY` for document scroll amounts, and the position of the canvas within the document, to find where the click occured in the canvas.

Although not yet fully standardized, [`offsetX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) and [`offsetY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetY) properties of the mouse event object provide the result directly. The MDN reference shows fairly good cross browser support.

Then knowledge of canvas layout can be used to determine which rectangular circle *pattern* was clicked, and with a bit of algebra if the click is inside the circle.

Comment: I've made this jsfiddle as a start, how to proceed from here?https://jsfiddle.net/cmxLoqej/